# Can dplyr summarise over several variables without listing each one?

Tags: r, dplyr

dplyr is amazingly fast, but I wonder if I'm missing something: is it possible summarise over several variables.  For example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

df <- data.frame(
  sex = factor(rep(c("boy", "girl"), each = 2L)),
  age = c(52L, 58L, 40L, 62L),
  bmi = c(25L, 23L, 30L, 26L),
  chol = c(187L, 220L, 190L, 204L)
)
df

   sex age bmi chol
1  boy  52  25  187
2  boy  58  23  220
3 girl  40  30  190
4 girl  62  26  204

dg=group_by(df,sex)
```

With this small dataframe, it's easy to write

```
summarise(dg,mean(age),mean(bmi),mean(chol))
```

And I know that to get what I want, I could melt, get the means, and then dcast such as

```
dm=melt(df, id.var='sex')
dmg=group_by(dm, sex, variable); 
x=summarise(dmg, means=mean(value))
dcast(x, sex~variable)
```

But what if I have >20 variables and a very large number of rows.  Is there anything similar to .SD in data.table that would allow me to take the means of all variables in the grouped data frame?  Or, is it possible to somehow use lapply on the grouped data frame?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I think the `data.table` solution will be the fastest and the more efficient here. But you can have a nice "`reshape2` only" solution : `dcast(melt(df, id = "sex"), sex ~ variable, fun.aggregate = mean)`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The `data.table` idiom is `lapply(.SD, mean)`, which is

```
DT <- data.table(df)
DT[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = sex]
#     sex age bmi  chol
# 1:  boy  55  24 203.5
# 2: girl  51  28 197.0
```

I'm not sure of a `dplyr` idiom for the same thing, but you can do something like

```
dg <- group_by(df, sex)
# the names of the columns you want to summarize
cols <- names(dg)[-1]
# the dots component of your call to summarise
dots <- sapply(cols ,function(x) substitute(mean(x), list(x=as.name(x))))
do.call(summarise, c(list(.data=dg), dots))
# Source: local data frame [2 x 4]

#    sex age bmi  chol
# 1  boy  55  24 203.5
# 2 girl  51  28 197.0
```

Note that there is a github issue [#178](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/178) to efficienctly implement the `plyr` idiom `colwise` in `dplyr`.

Comment: I'd say that's currently the best you can do with dplyr. The only change I'd make it to replace `sapply()` with `lapply()` since there's no simplification happening.

Comment: Note there is now summarize_each() and mutate_each() in dplyr: http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/dplyr/html/summarise_each.html

Answer (score 121):

As has been mentioned by several folks, `mutate_each()` and `summarise_each()` are deprecated in favour of the new `across()` function.

Answer as of `dplyr` version 1.0.5:

```
df %>%
  group_by(sex) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), mean))
```

Original answer:

`dplyr` now has `summarise_each`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(sex) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(mean))
```

Comment: Version update of `summarise_each` alternatives can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39284283/5088194

Comment: Yes, as `summarise_each` has been deprecated you may now want to use `summarise_all` or something similar for the OP's application.

Comment: `summarise_each` has been deprecated. `df %>% group_by(sex) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), mean))`