# How to use dplyr for programming

Tags: r, cran, dplyr

I like `dplyr` for data manipulation, but I don't understand how to use it for programming. For example, to rescale some variables, we could do:

```
mutate(cars, speed.scaled = scale(speed), dist.scaled = scale(dist))
```

Very cool. But now suppose I want to write a function that uses `mutate` to scale all variables in a data frame. How do I create the `...` argument? The best thing I can come up with is something like:

```
fnargs <- lapply(names(cars), function(x){call("scale", as.name(x))})
names(fnargs) <- paste0(names(cars), ".scaled")
do.call(mutate, c(.data=as.name("cars"), fnargs))
```

Or is there an alternative interface that is more programming friendly?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295936/

Comment: we'll get there: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/178

Answer (score 4):

Easy peasy: use `mutate_each(cars, funs(scale))` or `apply(cars, 2, scale)`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in base R like this:

```
cars.scaled <- as.data.frame(scale(cars))
```

or

```
cars.scaled <- replace(cars, TRUE, lapply(cars, scale))
```

or

```
cars.scaled <- cars
cars.scaled[] <- lapply(cars, scale)
```

The first one above can be translated to work with `%>%` like this:

```
cars.scaled <- cars %>% scale %>% as.data.frame
```