# Summarizing multiple columns with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

I'm struggling a bit with the dplyr-syntax. I have a data frame with different variables and one grouping variable. Now I want to calculate the mean for each column within each group, using dplyr in R.

```
df <- data.frame(
    a = sample(1:5, n, replace = TRUE), 
    b = sample(1:5, n, replace = TRUE), 
    c = sample(1:5, n, replace = TRUE), 
    d = sample(1:5, n, replace = TRUE), 
    grp = sample(1:3, n, replace = TRUE)
)
df %>% group_by(grp) %>% summarise(mean(a))
```

This gives me the mean for column "a" for each group indicated by "grp".

My question is: is it possible to get the means for each column within each group at once? Or do I have to repeat `df %>% group_by(grp) %>% summarise(mean(a))` for each column?

What I would like to have is something like

```
df %>% group_by(grp) %>% summarise(mean(a:d)) # "mean(a:d)" does not work
```

Answer (score 299, accepted):

In `dplyr` (>=1.00) you may use `across(everything()` in `summarise` to apply a function to all variables:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(grp) %>% summarise(across(everything(), list(mean)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>     grp     a     b     c     d
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1  3.08  2.98  2.98  2.91
#> 2     2  3.03  3.04  2.97  2.87
#> 3     3  2.85  2.95  2.95  3.06
```

Alternatively, the `purrrlyr` package provides the same functionality:

```r
library(purrrlyr)
df %>% slice_rows("grp") %>% dmap(mean)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>     grp     a     b     c     d
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1  3.08  2.98  2.98  2.91
#> 2     2  3.03  3.04  2.97  2.87
#> 3     3  2.85  2.95  2.95  3.06
```

Also don't forget about `data.table` (use `keyby` to sort groups):

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, mean), keyby = grp]
#>    grp        a        b        c        d
#> 1:   1 3.079412 2.979412 2.979412 2.914706
#> 2:   2 3.029126 3.038835 2.967638 2.873786
#> 3:   3 2.854701 2.948718 2.951567 3.062678
```

Let's try to compare performance.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrrlyr)
library(data.table)
library(bench)
set.seed(123)
n <- 10000
df <- data.frame(
  a = sample(1:5, n, replace = TRUE), 
  b = sample(1:5, n, replace = TRUE), 
  c = sample(1:5, n, replace = TRUE), 
  d = sample(1:5, n, replace = TRUE), 
  grp = sample(1:3, n, replace = TRUE)
)
dt <- setDT(df)
mark(
  dplyr = df %>% group_by(grp) %>% summarise(across(everything(), list(mean))),
  purrrlyr = df %>% slice_rows("grp") %>% dmap(mean),
  data.table = dt[, lapply(.SD, mean), keyby = grp],
  check = FALSE
)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 dplyr        2.81ms   2.85ms      328.        NA     17.3
#> 2 purrrlyr     7.96ms   8.04ms      123.        NA     24.5
#> 3 data.table 596.33µs 707.91µs     1409.        NA     10.3
```

Comment: This is nice, but what should I do if I just want to apply function, i.e. `paste` to the last column, and for others columns I just want to take the first element or leave as-is?

Comment: I mean, the behavior like in `select` would be great: `summarize(df, a:c, d=paste(d, collaspe =',' )` . Just want to put more original columns in for reference

Comment: difference between purrr and dplyr pls ?

Comment: How can I  add argument to mean function in that case?`mean(na.rm = TRUE)` into: `df %>% group_by(grp) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean))`

Comment: @piotr: `funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE))` instead `funs(mean)`.

Comment: @ArtemKlevtsov In `purrr v0.2.4` both `slice_rows` and `dmap` have been removed. Do you know what are the alternatives to do the same thing in the newer release of `purrr`?
I guess `purrr` isn't really necessary and the same can be done with- `iris %>% dplyr::group_by(Species) %>% dplyr::mutate_all(mean) %>% distinct()`, but just wanted to have knowledge of doing the same with `purrr`.

Comment: `dmap` moved to the `purrrlyr` package.

Comment: Instead of `summarise_all(funs(mean))`, I find the following syntax more intuitive to read: `summarise_all(.funs = mean)`

Comment: @ArtemKlevtsov
Dplyr performance has improved a lot. The current version, 0.8.3, performs at about 2.1 relative to data.table. (Contrast with about 7.0 relative to data.table in the table above.)

Comment: @ArtemKlevtsov is there a way to summarize multiple columns into rows just with the summary function being count (n that are positive) and proportion (%)?

Comment: @ArtemKlevtsov, the summary values in your example aren't the same..? mean for column a, grp 3 is 4.00 in the first two examples and 3.714 in data.table? Was this a different iteration of `df`?

Comment: @mark-verhagen, thank you for the note. Answer updated.

Comment: perhaps we should update for dplyr 1.0 with `across` replacement of the summarise suffixes

Comment: The ```list(mean)))``` should be just ```mean```. The code renamed my variables otherwise.

Comment: Is it possible to apply different functions to differents sets of columns ?

Answer (score 67):

We can summarize by using `summarize_at`, `summarize_all` and `summarize_if` on `dplyr 0.7.4`. We can set the multiple columns and functions by using `vars` and `funs` argument as below code. The left-hand side of funs formula is assigned to suffix of summarized vars. In the `dplyr 0.7.4`, `summarise_each`(and `mutate_each`) is already deprecated, so we cannot use these functions.

```r
options(scipen = 100, dplyr.width = Inf, dplyr.print_max = Inf)

library(dplyr)
packageVersion("dplyr")
# [1] ‘0.7.4’

set.seed(123)
df <- data_frame(
  a = sample(1:5, 10, replace=T), 
  b = sample(1:5, 10, replace=T), 
  c = sample(1:5, 10, replace=T), 
  d = sample(1:5, 10, replace=T), 
  grp = as.character(sample(1:3, 10, replace=T)) # For convenience, specify character type
)

df %>% group_by(grp) %>% 
  summarise_each(.vars = letters[1:4],
                 .funs = c(mean="mean"))
# `summarise_each()` is deprecated.
# Use `summarise_all()`, `summarise_at()` or `summarise_if()` instead.
# To map `funs` over a selection of variables, use `summarise_at()`
# Error: Strings must match column names. Unknown columns: mean
```

You should change to the following code. The following codes all have the same result.

```
# summarise_at
df %>% group_by(grp) %>% 
  summarise_at(.vars = letters[1:4],
               .funs = c(mean="mean"))

df %>% group_by(grp) %>% 
  summarise_at(.vars = names(.)[1:4],
               .funs = c(mean="mean"))

df %>% group_by(grp) %>% 
  summarise_at(.vars = vars(a,b,c,d),
               .funs = c(mean="mean"))

# summarise_all
df %>% group_by(grp) %>% 
  summarise_all(.funs = c(mean="mean"))

# summarise_if
df %>% group_by(grp) %>% 
  summarise_if(.predicate = function(x) is.numeric(x),
               .funs = funs(mean="mean"))
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# grp a_mean b_mean c_mean d_mean
# <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     1   2.80   3.00    3.6   3.00
# 2     2   4.25   2.75    4.0   3.75
# 3     3   3.00   5.00    1.0   2.00
```

You can also have multiple functions.

```
df %>% group_by(grp) %>% 
  summarise_at(.vars = letters[1:2],
               .funs = c(Mean="mean", Sd="sd"))
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# grp a_Mean b_Mean      a_Sd     b_Sd
# <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1     1   2.80   3.00 1.4832397 1.870829
# 2     2   4.25   2.75 0.9574271 1.258306
# 3     3   3.00   5.00        NA       NA
```

Comment: Is it possible can i apply the each column with each function,
i.e, for column `a`  apply only the `mean` and for column `b` apply only the `sd `
with using the summaise_at

Comment: @user7462639 In your case, you can use `summarise`. i.e, `summarise(a_mean = mean(a), b_sd = sd(b))`

Comment: but what if i want to do mean for columns 1-13, sd for columns 14-30, sum for columns 31-100, and don't want to list them all out?

Comment: I upvoted your comment because I posted yesterday this question [R summarise_at dynamically by condition : mean for some columns, sum for others](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60306857/10489562).

Answer (score 42):

You can simply pass more arguments to `summarise`:

```
df %>% group_by(grp) %>% summarise(mean(a), mean(b), mean(c), mean(d))
```

Source: local data frame [3 x 5]

```
  grp  mean(a)  mean(b)  mean(c) mean(d)
1   1 2.500000 3.500000 2.000000     3.0
2   2 3.800000 3.200000 3.200000     2.8
3   3 3.666667 3.333333 2.333333     3.0
```

Comment: Great! Is it even possible to do such things if column names and count are unknown? E.g. having 3 or 6 instead of 4 fixed columns?

Comment: That is a TODO in `dplyr` I believe (like `plyr` `colwise`), see here for a rather awkward current solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21296364/1527403

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you! I'll probably just use a loop to iterate all columns.

Comment: `dplyr` now has `summarise_each` which will operate on each column

Comment: `dplyr` has now superseded `summarise_*` with `summarise(across(....` as of `dplyr` 1.0.0

Answer (score 7):

For completeness: with dplyr v0.2 `ddply` with `colwise` will also do this:

```
> ddply(df, .(grp), colwise(mean))
  grp        a    b        c        d
1   1 4.333333 4.00 1.000000 2.000000
2   2 2.000000 2.75 2.750000 2.750000
3   3 3.000000 4.00 4.333333 3.666667
```

but it is slower, at least in this case:

```
> microbenchmark(ddply(df, .(grp), colwise(mean)), 
                  df %>% group_by(grp) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean)))
Unit: milliseconds
                                            expr      min       lq     mean
                ddply(df, .(grp), colwise(mean))     3.278002 3.331744 3.533835
 df %>% group_by(grp) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean)) 1.001789 1.031528 1.109337

   median       uq      max neval
 3.353633 3.378089 7.592209   100
 1.121954 1.133428 2.292216   100
```

Comment: Need test on the large dataset.

Comment: `ddply` is not in `dplyr`, it's in `plyr`.

Answer (score 5):

All the examples are great, but I figure I'd add one more to show how working in a "tidy" format simplifies things. Right now the data frame is in "wide" format meaning the variables "a" through "d" are represented in columns. To get to a "tidy" (or long) format, you can use `gather()` from the `tidyr` package which shifts the variables in columns "a" through "d" into rows. Then you use the `group_by()` and `summarize()` functions to get the mean of each group. If you want to present the data in a wide format, just tack on an additional call to the `spread()` function.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Create reproducible df
set.seed(101)
df <- tibble(a   = sample(1:5, 10, replace=T), 
             b   = sample(1:5, 10, replace=T), 
             c   = sample(1:5, 10, replace=T), 
             d   = sample(1:5, 10, replace=T), 
             grp = sample(1:3, 10, replace=T))

# Convert to tidy format using gather
df %>%
    gather(key = variable, value = value, a:d) %>%
    group_by(grp, variable) %>%
    summarize(mean = mean(value)) %>%
    spread(variable, mean)
#> Source: local data frame [3 x 5]
#> Groups: grp [3]
#> 
#>     grp        a     b        c        d
#> * <int>    <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     1 3.000000   3.5 3.250000 3.250000
#> 2     2 1.666667   4.0 4.666667 2.666667
#> 3     3 3.333333   3.0 2.333333 2.333333
```

Comment: That's another nice approach to keep in mind. Just one thing: I don't agree with Hadley's definition of tidy data always being in long format. Often, you don't want to multiply your observations, but want to have one row per observation.

Comment: I don't disagree. Everyone has preferences and for some the wide approach is preferable either from a more intuitive perspective or because there are actually structural reasons you don't want long format. For me, my preference is long format because as I began working with `dplyr` more the long format makes things much easier.