# Incorrect function output

Tags: r, function

The following is an example based on a small subset of my data:

```
NAME <- c("SYNOP", "SYNOP", "METAR", "METAR", "SYNOP", "METAR")
AIR <-  c(6.7, 8.3, 9.2, 8.9, 9.1, 8.7)
Example <- data.frame(NAME, AIR)

   NAME AIR
1 SYNOP 6.7
2 SYNOP 8.3
3 METAR 9.2
4 METAR 8.9
5 SYNOP 9.1
6 METAR 8.7
```

I am using grep to select a subset of this data where NAME == METAR and find out the number of occurences:

```
ex_METAR <- Example[grep("METAR", Example$NAME), ]
nrow(ex_METAR)
```

I have to repeat this for a large number of instances of `NAME` and wanted to speed this process up by making use of it in a function.  However I must be doing something wrong as I get an error message each time:

```
example_Function <- function (A, B, C) {
A[grep("B", A$C), ]
}

> example_Function(Example, "METAR", Example$NAME)
[1] NAME AIR 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I have thought it was how I am describing "METAR" so I've tried the function with only A and C and get the same error.

```
example_Function <- function (A, C) {
A[grep("METAR", A$C), ]
}
example_Function(Example, Example$NAME)
```

Is there something I'm actively doing wrong or will this simply just not work? I've never tried to adapt a function in this way before. Or maybe a function is the wrong way to go?! Thanks in advance.

(Not a duplicate of [Aggregate a dataframe on a given column and display another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289538/aggregate-a-dataframe-on-a-given-column-and-display-another-column) which is looking for subsetting with maximums. I need to subset for the words in a column and know how many times that has happened.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aggregate a dataframe on a given column and display another column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289538/aggregate-a-dataframe-on-a-given-column-and-display-another-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for :

```
NAME <- c("SYNOP", "SYNOP", "METAR", "METAR", "SYNOP", "METAR")
AIR <-  c(6.7, 8.3, 9.2, 8.9, 9.1, 8.7)
Example <- data.frame(NAME, AIR)

library(dplyr)

Example %>% group_by(NAME) %>% summarize(Count=n())
```

Output :

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

    NAME Count
  (fctr) (int)
1  METAR     3
2  SYNOP     3
```

Comment: Yup that's pretty much the non-convoluted way of doing that! Thank you

Comment: Could you please mark it as the answer, if it solved your issue. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @prateek1592, I have, you just have to wait before you are allowed to accept an answer.

I have one further question, could I perhaps incorporate a loop or apply into this? I actually have quite a few columns in the same table I need to apply this code too (not in the example!)

Comment: Ah, I see. So do you want to 1) Group by more than one column at the same time? Or 2) Group multiple times, taking one column at a time?

Comment: Multiple times. I have columns such as ID and SOURCE that need to be grouped by different variables as well. I know I can just execute the code numerous times but the number of columns is going to increase over time

Comment: I think you can try to loop over this code. No better solution comes to mind at the moment...

Comment: I guess so, but it hasn't worked so far! It outputs the wrong thing even before I add more columns (also does it after ofc)

`testf <- function(i, j) {
i %>% group_by((j)) %>% summarize(Count=n())
}
#Works perfect for testf(Example, NAME)

vector <- c("NAME")

for(i in 1:length(vector)) {
Test <- testf(Example, vector[i])
print(Test)
}`

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for - http://stackoverflow.com/a/32336788/5908050 ?