# How to count number of values in columns based on a category in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

Suppose we have a data frame `df` like

```
book_id book_category book_word_hi book_word_bye book_word_yes
1       drama         3            0             4
2       action        1            4             5
3       drama         5            3             2
```

I would like to count the number of values within the `book_word` columns and sum them in a table for each `book_category`.

So the output here should look something like:

```
drama: 17 
action: 10
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a short and simple one-liner in base R, without requiring any additional packages.

```r
tapply(rowSums(df[3:5]), df[2], sum)
#> book_category
#> action  drama 
#>     10     17
```

Answer (score 4):

Here, there can be also other columns like `book_word_foo` as well, which will be counted:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(
  ~book_id, ~book_category, ~book_word_hi, ~book_word_bye, ~book_word_yes,
  1, "drama", 3, 0, 4,
  2, "action", 1, 4, 5,
  2, "drama", 5, 3, 2,
)

data %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(book_id, book_category)) %>%
  group_by(book_category) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(value))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   book_category     n
#>   <chr>         <dbl>
#> 1 action           10
#> 2 drama            17
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

First sum up every columns that `starts_with` the string "book_word". Then `group_by` and `sum` up the values per `book_category`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(book_sum = rowSums(across(starts_with("book_word")))) %>% 
  group_by(book_category) %>% 
  summarize(sum = sum(book_sum))

# A tibble: 2 × 2
  book_category   sum
  <chr>         <int>
1 action           10
2 drama            17
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the function `summarise_at` [link to docs](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html):

```
df %>%
  summarise_at(c("book_word_hi","book_word_bye","book_word_yes"), sum, na.rm = FALSE)
```

Could also be combined with a group_by

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to adapt the code using column index rather than column name? E.g. `c([3:5])`? @Mads

Comment: Yes I think so. Check the docs that I linked to. You can use select-style statements like: ```summarise_at(vars(book_word_hi:book_word_yes), mean, na.rm = FALSE)```to select many variables at once

Comment: You can also use column indexing. Checkout this other SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45883513/using-dplyr-summarise-at-with-column-index

Answer (score 1):

Using `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(book_sum ~ book_category, transform(data, book_sum = rowSums(data[3:5])), sum)
  book_category book_sum
1        action       10
2         drama       17
```