# R summarise_at dynamically by condition : mean for some columns, sum for others

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, dplyr, dbplyr

I would like that but with the conditions in the `summarise_at()`

**Edit #1**: I've added the word dynamically in the title: When I use `vars(c())` in the `summarise_at()` it's for fast and clear examples, but in fact it's for use `contains()`, `starts_with()` and `matches(,, perl=TRUE)`, because I have 50 columns, with many `sum()` and some `mean()`.

And the goal is for generate dynamic SQL with `tbl()..%>% group_by() ... %>% summarise_at()...%>% collect()`.

**Edit #2**: I added example with SQL generated in my second example

```
library(tidyverse)
(mtcars 
  %>% group_by(carb)
  %>% summarise_at(vars(c("mpg","cyl","disp")), list (~mean(.),~sum(.)))
  # I don't want this line below, I would like a conditional in summarise_at() because I have 50 columns in my real case
  %>% select(carb,cyl_mean,disp_mean,mpg_sum)
)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>    carb cyl_mean disp_mean mpg_sum
#>   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1     1     4.57      134.   177. 
#> 2     2     5.6       208.   224  
#> 3     3     8         276.    48.9
#> 4     4     7.2       309.   158. 
#> 5     6     6         145     19.7
#> 6     8     8         301     15

Created on 2020-02-19 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)
```

This works, but I want only sum for mpg, and only mean for cyl and disp:

```
library(RSQLite)
library(dbplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(DBI)

db <- dbConnect(SQLite(),":memory:")

dbCreateTable(db, "mtcars_table", mtcars)

(tbl( db, build_sql( con=db,"select * from mtcars_table" ))
  %>% group_by(carb)
  %>% summarise_at(vars(c("mpg","cyl","disp")), list (~mean(.),~sum(.)))
  %>% select(carb,cyl_mean,disp_mean,mpg_sum)                   
  %>% show_query()
)
#> <SQL>
#> Warning: Missing values are always removed in SQL.[...]  to silence this warning
#> SELECT `carb`, `cyl_mean`, `disp_mean`, `mpg_sum`
#> FROM (SELECT `carb`, AVG(`mpg`) AS `mpg_mean`, AVG(`cyl`) AS `cyl_mean`, AVG(`disp`) AS `disp_mean`, SUM(`mpg`) AS `mpg_sum`, SUM(`cyl`) AS `cyl_sum`, SUM(`disp`) AS `disp_sum`
#> FROM (select * from mtcars_table)
#> GROUP BY `carb`)
#> # Source:   lazy query [?? x 4]
#> # Database: sqlite 3.30.1 [:memory:]
#> # … with 4 variables: carb <dbl>, cyl_mean <lgl>, disp_mean <lgl>,
#> #   mpg_sum <lgl>
```

I tried all possibilities like that but it doesn't work or it produces error.

```
(mtcars %>% group_by(carb)%>% summarise_at(vars(c("mpg","cyl","disp")),ifelse(vars(contains(names(.),"mpg")),list(sum(.)),list(mean(.)))) )
```

Not good, too many columns

```
library(tidyverse)
(mtcars %>% group_by(carb)%>% summarise_at(vars(c("mpg","cyl","disp")),ifelse ((names(.)=="mpg"), list(~sum(.)) , list(~mean(.)))))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 34
#>    carb mpg_sum cyl_sum disp_sum mpg_mean..2 cyl_mean..2 disp_mean..2
#>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1     1   177.       32     940.        25.3        4.57         134.
#> 2     2   224        56    2082.        22.4        5.6          208.
#> 3     3    48.9      24     827.        16.3        8            276.
#> 4     4   158.       72    3088.        15.8        7.2          309.
#> 5     6    19.7       6     145         19.7        6            145 
#> 6     8    15         8     301         15          8            301 
#> # … with 27 more variables: mpg_mean..3 <dbl>, cyl_mean..3 <dbl>,
#> #   disp_mean..3 <dbl>, mpg_mean..4 <dbl>, cyl_mean..4 <dbl>,
#> #   disp_mean..4 <dbl>, mpg_mean..5 <dbl>, cyl_mean..5 <dbl>,
#> #   disp_mean..5 <dbl>, mpg_mean..6 <dbl>, cyl_mean..6 <dbl>,
#> #   disp_mean..6 <dbl>, mpg_mean..7 <dbl>, cyl_mean..7 <dbl>,
#> #   disp_mean..7 <dbl>, mpg_mean..8 <dbl>, cyl_mean..8 <dbl>,
#> #   disp_mean..8 <dbl>, mpg_mean..9 <dbl>, cyl_mean..9 <dbl>,
#> #   disp_mean..9 <dbl>, mpg_mean..10 <dbl>, cyl_mean..10 <dbl>,
#> #   disp_mean..10 <dbl>, mpg_mean..11 <dbl>, cyl_mean..11 <dbl>,
#> #   disp_mean..11 <dbl>
```

Some other attempts and remarks: I would like conditional `sum(.)` or `mean(.)` depending of the name of the column in the `summarise()`.

It could be good if it accepts not only primitive functions.

At then end it's for `tbl()..%>% group_by() ... %>% summarise_at()...%>% collect()` to generate conditional SQL with `AVG()` and `SUM()`.

T-SQL function like `~(convert(varchar())` works for `mutate_at()` and similar `~AVG()`works for `summarise_at()` but I arrive at the same point: conditional `summarise_at()` doesn't work depending of name of columns.

:)

Answer (score 3):

An option is to `group_by` the 'carb',  and then create the `sum` of 'mpg' as another grouping variable and then use `summarise_at` with the rest of the variables needed

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
    group_by(carb) %>%
    group_by(mpg_sum = sum(mpg), .add = TRUE) %>%
    summarise_at(vars(cyl, disp), list(mean = mean))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   carb [6]
#   carb mpg_sum cyl_mean disp_mean
#  <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#1     1   177.      4.57      134.
#2     2   224       5.6       208.
#3     3    48.9     8         276.
#4     4   158.      7.2       309.
#5     6    19.7     6         145 
#6     8    15       8         301
```

---

Or using the `devel` version of `dplyr`, this can be done in a single `summarise` by wrapping the blocks of columns in `across` and the single column by themselves and apply different functions on it

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(carb) %>% 
  summarise(across(one_of(c("cyl", "disp")), list(mean = mean)), 
            mpg_sum = sum(mpg))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#   carb cyl_mean disp_mean mpg_sum
#  <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     1     4.57      134.   177. 
#2     2     5.6       208.   224  
#3     3     8         276.    48.9
#4     4     7.2       309.   158. 
#5     6     6         145     19.7
#6     8     8         301     15
```

NOTE: `summarise_at/summarise_if/mutate_at/mutate_if/...` etc. will be superseded by the `across` verb with the default functions (`summarise/mutate/filter/...`) in the upcoming releases

Comment: Tomorrow I will try both on my real case including Mssql generation with that :)

Comment: I've not try yet but your solution 1 has a lack for me :) : the first grouping function `sum(mpg)` is not dynamic. When I use `vars(c())` it's for fast and clear examples, but in fact it's for use `contains()`, `Starts_With()` and `matches(,, perl=TRUE)`, because I have 50 columns, with many `sum()` and some `mean()`. If I cannot use these dynamic functions, I would write SQL with `paste0()`. :)

Comment: I would prefer a solution with a function in the `summarise_at()` like my `(mtcars %>% group_by(carb)%>% summarise_at(vars(c("mpg","cyl","disp")),ifelse ((names(.)=="mpg"), list(~sum(.)) , list(~mean(.)))))` or your solution 2 if I could upgrade. The solution 1 is short but I have a doubt that the first `group_by() ` could be dynamic, not on grouping dim (`group_by_at()` could , but on dynamic indicators.

Comment: Your solution 1, with two `group_by()` doesn't work because `%>% group_by(carb, add = TRUE)` and after `%>% group_by(mpg_sum = sum(mpg))` creates `SUM(mpg) OVER (PARTITION BY carb)` in `show_query()` which is off-topic :) (and without speaking about dynamic selection of indicator).

Comment: I added example with SQL generated in my second example.

Comment: @phili_b YOu can make the `group_by` dynamic.  Is this going to be a function, then it would be `group_by({{yourvar}})` where `yourvar` will be unquoted column name passed into the function

Comment: Yes, maybe, but two `group_by()` make a SQL `group by` and the `sum over partition` that I don't want. :) I upvoted your answer because of your work and the information about the new feature `across()`, thanks, but for instance It isn't an accepted answer at my question with the actual version of dplyr. :) Please, look at my workarounded answer : it's this SQL I expect. I tried it on my real case : it works.. . but regex is not really in the tidyverse philosophy. :) I thought that generated SQL was possible with lambda or function in `summarise_at()` without `across()` but It doesn't :)

Comment: @phili_b with `summarise_at`, there is a limitation with the way you wanted to get the output.  I think  once the devel version is integrated with sql, the across would work

Comment: I prefer a feature with technical debt than no feature at all :-P (and I prefer that than `paste`ed SQL like I did before ).

Comment: @phili_b then it is better to request on dplyr github because they decide on that

Comment: [github.com/tidyverse/dplyr#4892 Feature Requested, across: Summarise by condition : mean for some columns dynamically, sum for others, non primitive function for others](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4892)

Comment: Conditionnal `summarise(across(..))` works well with dplyr > 1.x like as [@Hadley had answered to me before the 1.x release](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4892#issuecomment-590988780) : `df %>% summarise(  across(contains("price"), mean),  across(contains("quantity"), sum) )`. Technical debt fixed now because I have to return to these line to add new business functionalities to these lines.

Answer (score 2):

## workaround waiting `across()` with regex

```
library(RSQLite)
library(dbplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(DBI)

db <- dbConnect(SQLite())

mtcars_table <- mtcars %>% rename(mpg_sum=mpg,cyl_mean=cyl,disp_mean=disp )

RSQLite::dbWriteTable(db, "mtcars_table", mtcars_table)

req<-as.character((tbl( db, build_sql( con=db,"select * from mtcars_table" ))
                   %>% group_by(carb)
                   %>% summarise_at(vars(c(ends_with("mean"), ends_with("sum")) ), ~sum(.))

) %>% sql_render())
#> Warning: Missing values are always removed in SQL.
#> Use `SUM(x, na.rm = TRUE)` to silence this warning
#> This warning is displayed only once per session.

req<-gsub("(SUM)(\\(.{1,30}mean.{1,10}\\))", "AVG\\2", req, perl=TRUE)
print(req)
#> [1] "SELECT `carb`, AVG(`cyl_mean`) AS `cyl_mean`, AVG(`disp_mean`) AS `disp_mean`, 
# SUM(`mpg_sum`) AS `mpg_sum`\nFROM (select * from mtcars_table)\n
# GROUP BY `carb`"

dbGetQuery(db, req)
#>   carb cyl_mean disp_mean mpg_sum
#> 1    1 4.571429  134.2714   177.4
#> 2    2 5.600000  208.1600   224.0
#> 3    3 8.000000  275.8000    48.9
#> 4    4 7.200000  308.8200   157.9
#> 5    6 6.000000  145.0000    19.7
#> 6    8 8.000000  301.0000    15.0
```

## sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] DBI_1.1.0       forcats_0.4.0   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_0.8.4     purrr_0.3.3    
 [6] readr_1.3.1     tidyr_1.0.2     tibble_2.1.3    ggplot2_3.2.1   tidyverse_1.3.0
[11] dbplyr_1.4.2    RSQLite_2.2.0  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] xfun_0.10        tidyselect_1.0.0 haven_2.2.0      lattice_0.20-38  colorspace_1.4-1
 [6] vctrs_0.2.2      generics_0.0.2   htmltools_0.4.0  blob_1.2.1       rlang_0.4.4     
[11] pillar_1.4.3     glue_1.3.1       withr_2.1.2      bit64_0.9-7      modelr_0.1.5    
[16] readxl_1.3.1     lifecycle_0.1.0  munsell_0.5.0    gtable_0.3.0     cellranger_1.1.0
[21] rvest_0.3.5      memoise_1.1.0    evaluate_0.14    knitr_1.25       callr_3.3.2     
[26] ps_1.3.0         fansi_0.4.1      broom_0.5.2      Rcpp_1.0.3       clipr_0.7.0     
[31] scales_1.1.0     backports_1.1.5  jsonlite_1.6.1   fs_1.3.1         bit_1.1-15.1    
[36] hms_0.5.3        digest_0.6.23    stringi_1.4.5    processx_3.4.1   grid_3.6.1      
[41] cli_2.0.1        tools_3.6.1      magrittr_1.5     lazyeval_0.2.2   whisker_0.4     
[46] crayon_1.3.4     pkgconfig_2.0.3  xml2_1.2.2       reprex_0.3.0     lubridate_1.7.4 
[51] assertthat_0.2.1 rmarkdown_1.16   httr_1.4.1       rstudioapi_0.10  R6_2.4.1        
[56] nlme_3.1-141     compiler_3.6.1
```