# I have 5 columns and each has multiple values. Please help me find the median of each column using dplyr

Tags: r, median

How could I find the median value of a column in R. Each of my column has almost three to five values in it. The result should only be one value for each column.

Comment: Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644848/summarizing-multiple-columns-with-dplyr), and use the `median` function

Answer (score 0):

```
foo <- c(1,2,3)
median(foo)
```

And in a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
    a = c(1,2,3)
  )
median(df[,"a"])
```

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr` and using `iris` dataframe for example:

```
library(dplyr)
#Data
data("iris")
#Code
iris %>% select(-Species) %>% summarise_all(median,na.rm=T)
```

Output:

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1          5.8           3         4.35         1.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Example with mtcars:

sapply(mtcars, median)