# Summarising list of columns after group by

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, summarize

Is it possible to summarise big number of columns, without writing all their names?

My example:
I have a dataframe (dt) with one categorical column and a lot of numeric colunms:

```
Cat num1 num2 num3 ... num50
a   56   59   67   ... 89
a   46   66   27   ... 59
b   15   9    75   ... 43
b   45   29   35   ... 93
```

I make the following operation:

```
dt %>% group_by(Cat) %>% summarize(num1 = sum(num1), num2 = sum(num2), ... num50= sum(num50))
```

But writing all the 50 column names takes too long time!
Can I write this summarize expression shorter? I tried this variant, but it doesn't work:

```
dt %>% 
  group_by(Cat) %>% 
  summarize(num1:num50 = sum(c(num1:num50)))
```

Help me, please, how to write it laconically using dplyr of data.table (or other libraries).

Comment: I think this post might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644848/summarizing-multiple-columns-with-dplyr

Answer (score 0):

```
dt %>% group_by(Cat) %>% summarize_all(sum, na.rm=T)
```

Also, the `_all` dplyr verbs have been superseded by the use of `across`, so you can do something like this:

```
dt %>% group_by(Cat) %>% summarize(across(everything(), sum, na.rm=T))
```

Or, if you have other columns as well, you can specify the `num` columns directly like this

```
dt %>% group_by(Cat) %>% summarize(across(starts_with("num"), sum, na.rm=T))
```