# dplyr: How to use group_by inside a function?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval, nse

I want to use use the `dplyr::group_by` function inside another function, but I do not know how to pass the arguments to this function.

Can someone provide a working example?

```
library(dplyr)
data(iris)
iris %.% group_by(Species) %.% summarise(n = n()) # 
## Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
##      Species  n
## 1  virginica 50
## 2 versicolor 50
## 3     setosa 50

mytable0 <- function(x, ...) x %.% group_by(...) %.% summarise(n = n())
mytable0(iris, "Species") # OK
## Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
##      Species  n
## 1  virginica 50
## 2 versicolor 50
## 3     setosa 50

mytable1 <- function(x, key) x %.% group_by(as.name(key)) %.% summarise(n = n())
mytable1(iris, "Species") # Wrong!
# Error: unsupported type for column 'as.name(key)' (SYMSXP)

mytable2 <- function(x, key) x %.% group_by(key) %.% summarise(n = n())
mytable2(iris, "Species") # Wrong!
# Error: index out of bounds
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can dplyr summarise over several variables without listing each one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295936/can-dplyr-summarise-over-several-variables-without-listing-each-one)

Comment: Copying this exactly, `iris %.% group_by(Species) %.% summarise(n = n())` causes `Error in n() : This function should not be called directly`. WTF?! dplyr 0.1.2, R 3.0.3

Comment: ^ This is the known gotcha caused by wrongly loading dplyr first, then plyr, causing essential fns like `mutate, summarize, arrange, desc, ...` to be masked. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22801153/ddply-group-by-function-function-should-not-be-called-directly/

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34186903/error-when-using-dplyr-inside-of-a-function

Answer (score 78, accepted):

For programming, `group_by_` is the counterpart to `group_by`:

```
library(dplyr)

mytable <- function(x, ...) x %>% group_by_(...) %>% summarise(n = n())
mytable(iris, "Species")
# or iris %>% mytable("Species")
```

which gives:

```
     Species  n
1     setosa 50
2 versicolor 50
3  virginica 50
```

**Update** At the time this was written dplyr used `%.%` which is what was originally used above but now `%>%` is favored so have changed above to that to keep this relevant.

**Update 2** regroup is now deprecated, use group_by_ instead.

**Update 3** `group_by_(list(...))` now becomes `group_by_(...)` in new version of dplyr as per Roberto's comment.

**Update 4** Added minor variation suggested in comments.

**Update 5:** With rlang/tidyeval it is now possible to do this:

```
library(rlang)
mytable <- function(x, ...) {
  group_ <- syms(...)
  x %>% 
    group_by(!!!group_) %>% 
    summarise(n = n())
}
mytable(iris, "Species")
```

or passing `Species` unevaluated, i.e. no quotes around it:

```
library(rlang)
mytable <- function(x, ...) {
  group_ <- enquos(...)
  x %>% 
    group_by(!!!group_) %>% 
    summarise(n = n())
}
mytable(iris, Species)
```

**Update 6:**  There is now a {{...}} notation that works if there is just one grouping variable:

```
mytable <- function(x, group) {
  x %>% 
    group_by({{group}}) %>% 
    summarise(n = n())
}
mytable(iris, Species)
```

Comment: There is no need for the `as.name` etc. `mytable <- function(x, ...)  x %.% regroup(value = list(...)) %.% summarise(n = n()); mytable(x,'key1','key2') , or  `mytable <- function(x, key)  x %.% regroup(value = as.list(key) %.% summarise(n = n()); mytable(x, list('key1','key2'))` to allow grouping by more than one column

Comment: Thanks. Have replaced `as.name(key)` with `...` .

Comment: Now it's even simpler in dplyr 0.3 with lazyeval:

`mytable <- function(x, ...) x %>% group_by_(...) %>% summarise(n = n())`

Comment: @Roberto's solution can be rephrased using magrittr's notion of *functional sequence*: With `mytable <- function(...) . %>% group_by_(...) %>% summarise(n = n())`, `mytable("Species")` gives a functional sequence, so `iris %>% mytable("Species")()` gives the desired summary. (Note that the calling `()` is necessary—a minor "wart.") Of course, whether this extra degree of decoupling is worthwhile will depend on the specific application.

Answer (score 13):

**UPDATE**: As of dplyr 0.7.0 you can use tidy eval to accomplish this.

See http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html for more details.

```
library(tidyverse)
data("iris")

my_table <- function(df, group_var) {
  group_var <- enquo(group_var)      # Create quosure
  df %>% 
    group_by(!!group_var) %>%        # Use !! to unquote the quosure
    summarise(n = n())
}

my_table(iris, Species)

> my_table(iris, Species)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
     Species     n
      <fctr> <int>
1     setosa    50
2 versicolor    50
3  virginica    50
```

Comment: Doesn't n() give you a note when doing a check?

Comment: Hi @Elin. I'm not exactly sure what you mean. I just reran this code and didn't see any notes.

Comment: In a package build check?

Comment: I see. I hadn't tried including this in a package. Does just using dply::n() resolve the note?

Comment: No. I think you may need to quote then unquote the whole expression.

Answer (score 7):

As a complement to the **Update 6** in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21817110/7002525) by @G. Grothendieck, if you want to use a **string** as an argument in your summary function, instead of embracing the argument with doubled braces (`{{`), you should use the `.data` pronoun as described in the [Programming vignette: Loop over multiple variables](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#loop-over-multiple-variables-1):

```
mytable <- function( x, group ) {
  x %>% 
    group_by( .data[[group]] ) %>% 
    summarise( n = n() )
}

group_string <- 'Species'

mytable( iris, group_string )

`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Species        n
  <fct>      <int>
1 setosa        50
2 versicolor    50
3 virginica     50
```

Comment: Thanks! This is useful when using pmap.

Answer (score 2):

Ugly as they come, but she works:

```
mytable3 <- function(x, key) {
  my.call <- bquote(summarise(group_by(.(substitute(x)), NULL), n = n()))
  my.call[[2]][[3]] <- as.name(key)
  eval(my.call, parent.frame())
} 
mytable3(iris, "Species")
# Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
#
#      Species  n
# 1  virginica 50
# 2 versicolor 50
# 3     setosa 50
```

There are almost certainly cases that will cause this to break, but you get the idea.  I don't think you can get around messing with the call.  One other thing that did work but was even uglier is:

```
mytable4 <- function(x, key) summarise(group_by(x, x[[key]]), n = n())
```