# dplyr: "Error in n(): function should not be called directly"

Tags: r, function, plyr, dplyr, conflicting-libraries

I am attempting to reproduce one of the examples in the dplyr package but am getting this error message. I am expecting to see a new column n produced with the frequency of each combination.  What am I missing?  I triple checked that the package is loaded.

```
 library(dplyr)
# summarise peels off a single layer of grouping
by_vs_am <- group_by(mtcars, vs, am)

by_vs <- summarise(by_vs_am, n = n())
```

> Error in n() : This function should not be called directly

Answer (score 120, accepted):

I presume you have `dplyr` and `plyr` loaded in the same session. `dplyr` is not `plyr`. `ddply` is not a function in the `dplyr` package.

Both `dplyr` and `plyr` have the functions `summarise`/`summarize`.

Look at the results of `conflicts()` to see masked objects.

Comment: The solution is to make sure you load `plyr` first

Comment: As @User1257894 says, use `summarize` with the package, something like this `dplyr::summarize(count = n())`.

Answer (score 39):

As mentioned by the previous answer, you may have a conflict between plyr and dplyr. You can to run this command to unload the plyr package.

```
detach("package:plyr", unload=TRUE)
```

Then you can continue as expected.

```
library(dplyr) 
...
summarise(n = n())
```

Comment: Exactly... the conflict was between summarise or summarize. I also accidentally loaded `plyr` and `dplyr` packages in one of my project and realized this conflict. nice work mate.

Answer (score 26):

To avoid confusions with masking functions, it is clear to use the "package::function" specification, like example below:

```
delay <- dplyr::summarise(by_tailnum, 
  count = n(), 
  dist = mean(distance, na.rm = TRUE), 
  delay = mean(arr_delay, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 8):

In another case, this error occurred in the following code.

```r
library(dplyr) # dplyr 0.5.0
library(lazyeval)

df <- data_frame(group = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3))

g <- "group"

df %>%
  group_by_(g) %>%
  summarise_(
    n = n(),
    sum = interp(~sum(col, na.rm = TRUE), col = as.name(g))
  )
# Error in n() : This function should not be called directly
```

It can be solved as follows.

```r
df %>%
  group_by_(g) %>%
  summarise_(
    n = "n()",
    sum = interp(~sum(col, na.rm = TRUE), col = as.name(g))
  )
# A tibble: 3 × 3
# group     n   sum
# <dbl> <int> <dbl>
# 1     1     1     1
# 2     2     2     4
# 3     3     3     9
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar issue while executing code as per mentioned blog and then run solution in detach("package:plyr", unload=TRUE)

Blog : https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/09/comparative-stock-analysis/

```
Master_Data_AutoCorrelations<-Master_Data_lags %>%
  gather(key = "lag", value = "lag_value", -c(Stock,Date, Close)) %>%
  mutate(lag = str_sub(lag, start = 5) %>% as.numeric) %>%
  group_by(Stock, lag) %>%
  summarize(
    cor = cor(x = Close, y = lag_value, use = "pairwise.complete.obs"),
    cutoff_upper = 2/(n())^0.5,
    cutoff_lower = -2/(n())^0.5
  )
```

Post running detach,when above code was rerun it worked fine though received warning message as per below ,not sure whether plyr got unloaded or not.And how is the code executed properly ?

Warning message:
‘plyr’ namespace cannot be unloaded:
  namespace ‘plyr’ is imported by ‘reshape2’, ‘scales’, ‘broom’, ‘ggplot2’ so cannot be unloaded

Answer (score 0):

for me the solution was `detach()` function I utilized that function down package

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "I utilized that function down package"?

Comment: sorry I used the function detach() for down a package, I had the conflict between packages dplyr and knitr then use function for down package detach("package:knitr", unload=TRUE)