# Why doesn't summarize work the same way in dplyr and plyr?

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr

I'm running the example code for dplyr::summarize, and not getting the results I expect.

```
summarise(group_by(mtcars, cyl), 
          mean = mean(disp))
      mean
1 230.7219

ddply(mtcars, .(cyl), summarise,
       mean = mean(disp))
  cyl     mean
1   4 105.1364
2   6 183.3143
3   8 353.1000
```

What's going on here?

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
dplyr_0.1.2  
plyr_1.8
```

Comment: I'm also having similar issues.

Comment: It's most likely that you loaded `dplyr` first and then `plyr` after and then ran the code. Both have names `summarise` and it's calling `plyr:::summarise` in your first case. Try running `dplyr:::summarise(.)`

Comment: @Arun- looks great! Want to make that the answer so I can select it?

Comment: Or load plyr first and dplyr second.

Comment: See also [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22801153/ddply-error-in-n-function-should-not-be-called-directly).