# dplyr::n() returns "Error: This function should not be called directly"

Tags: r, dplyr

If I do:

```
dplyr::mutate(MeanValue = mean(RSSI), ReadCount = n())
```

everything works fine.
But when I try to qualify the function:

```
dplyr::mutate(MeanValue = mean(RSSI), ReadCount = dplyr::n())
```

I get the error mentioned in the title.

So, I do not really have a problem, I can just avoid doing that, but I'm curious about why it even happens. I already looked at another question ([dplyr: "Error in n(): function should not be called directly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22801153/dplyr-error-in-n-function-should-not-be-called-directly?noredirect=1&lq=1)), but as far as I know, dplyr is the only library I'm using. I tried doing what the answer suggests anyway, but

```
detach(package:plyr)
```

results in

> Error in detach(package:plyr) : invalid 'name' argument
>   and

```
conflicts()
```

does not mention n():

> [1] "filter"    "lag"       "body<-"    "intersect" "kronecker" "setdiff"   "setequal"  "union"
>   , most of which is cause by dplyr.

I guess I'm not the only one confused by this?

Comment: With a new session, the examples from `?n` works for me.

Comment: `n` in dplyr seems to be [mapped](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/src/dplyr.cpp#L445) to an internal function while `dplyr::n` cannot be treated equally and just calls the -error giving- R function.

Comment: Yes, it's better to think of `n` not as a R function but rather an argument to `summarize`, `mutate`, etc. that gets passed along to the C functions that know how to interpret it.

Comment: You loaded plyr I'm guessing

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> So, I do not really have a problem, I can just avoid [writing `dplyr::n()`], but I'm curious about why it even happens.

Here's the source code for `dplyr::n` in dplyr 0.5.0:

```
function () {
    stop("This function should not be called directly")
}
```

That's why the fully qualified form raises this error: the function always returns an error. (My guess is that the error-throwing function `dplyr::n` exists so that `n()` could have a typical documentation page with examples.)

Inside of `filter`/`mutate`/`summarise` statements, `n()` is not calling this function. Instead, some internal function calculates the group sizes for the expression `n()`. That's why the following works when dplyr is not loaded:

```
n()
#> Error: could not find function "n"

library(magrittr)
iris %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(Species) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(n = n())
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>      Species     n
#>       <fctr> <int>
#> 1     setosa    50
#> 2 versicolor    50
#> 3  virginica    50
```

Here `n()` cannot be mapped to a function, so we get an error. But when used it inside of a dplyr verb, `n()` does map to something and returns group sizes.

Comment: Okay, I still don't understand this design, but its still an answer. ;)

Answer (score 5):

I think this is coming as a result of masking between plyr and dplyr. 
Anyhow this solves it:

```
dplyr::summarise(count = n())
```

Comment: How do I apply this?

Answer (score 2):

I know I am 2 years late, but here’s my take.

The grouping in dplyr doesn’t actually *do* anything to the data. It just notes it’s grouped. This means the functions like mean or n need to be aware of this, and must infer from their wider context they should perform their calculations groupwise. They aren’t reallu R functions, which aren’t aware of this context. They are basically symbols that summarise() or mutate() choose to evaluate in a certain way (means or counts per group). I think Hadley chose to show an error if you call n() directly, as that’s slightly better than not having a function implemented at all.