# How does dplyr::n function work?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am curious about how the function `n` from `dplyr` is programmed. When evaluating `n` in the `dplyr` env, all I get is this:

```
function () 
{
    stop("This function should not be called directly")
}
<environment: namespace:dplyr>
```

Maybe it's a silly question but, where is it defined? How come it works when called inside some other functions? In which env is it hidden?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Good question. [The actual n() function](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/6153e136fa9397e88478fa6270d9d1f02eb5153e/R/manip.r#L337-L339) is easy to find, but it does not explain why `n()` works in `mutate`, `filter` and `summarise`. Could it be in the C code?

Comment: May be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39305474/dplyrn-returns-error-this-function-should-not-be-called-directly) helps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I understand, `dplyr` uses hybrid evaluation. That means it will evaluate some parts of the expression in C++ and others in R. `n()` is one of the functions that always gets handled by C++. This is why the function doesn't do anything in `R` directly, except for returning an error, since the function is never evaluated by R.

The relevant `C++` code can be found [on github](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/src/hybrid_count.cpp).

Comment: nice! interesting function... Actually it's educative that hadley (or whoever) wrote this function with the error in R, otherwise I would not have learned that!