# R group by | count distinct values grouping by another column

Tags: r

How can I count the number of distinct visit_ids per pagename?

```
visit_id  post_pagename
1       A
1       B
1       C
1       D 
2       A
2       A
3       A
3       B
```

Result should be:

```
post_pagename distinct_visit_ids
A     3
B     2
C     1
D     1
```

tried it with

```
test_df<-data.frame(cbind(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3),c("A","B","C","D","A","A","A","B")))
colnames(test_df)<-c("visit_id","post_pagename")
test_df

test_df %>%
 group_by(post_pagename) %>%
  summarize(vis_count = n_distinct(visit_id))
```

But this gives me only the amount of distinct visit_id in my data set

Comment: Why **D** did not include in the expected result. What is the difference between "number of distinct" and  "amount of distinct"

Comment: Sulimen, number and amount is the same. and yes, there could be D = 0, but its not necessary for me

Comment: How could it be that `D == 0` if there is one visit to `D` from `visit_id` `1` ?

Comment: ok, sorry, my mistake. i will correct it in my question posting

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### One way

```
test_df |>
  distinct() |>
  count(post_pagename)

#   post_pagename     n
#   <fct>         <int>
# 1 A                 3
# 2 B                 2
# 3 C                 1
# 4 D                 1
```

#### Or another

```
test_df |>
  group_by(post_pagename) |>
  summarise(distinct_visit_ids = n_distinct(visit_id))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  post_pagename distinct_visit_ids
#  <fct>                      <int>
#1 A                              3
#2 B                              2
#3 C                              1
#4 D                              1

*D has one visit, so it must be counted*
```

Comment: Maybe version-dependent. I got dplyr 0.7.4 on my machine.

Comment: utubun: I have 0.7.5

Comment: I get one row as result with  distinct_visit_ids = 3

Comment: I have no idea why it behave differently in my and your case.

Comment: ,..I'm gonna find ya.,..I'm gonna getcha getcha getcha

Answer (score 2):

The function `n_distinct()` will give you the number of distict rows in your data, as you have 2 rows that are "2 A", you should use only `n()`,that will count the number of times your groupped variable appears.

```
test_df<-data.frame(cbind(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3),c("A","B","C","D","A","A","A","B")))
colnames(test_df)<-c("visit_id","post_pagename")
test_df


test_df %>%
unique() %>%
group_by(post_pagename) %>%
summarize(vis_count = n())
```

This should work fine.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I get an error: Fehler: This function should not be called directly

Comment: Try dplyr::summarize(vis_count = n())

Comment: this mean you want the summarize function from dplyr package. You can see more about this error in here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22801153/dplyr-error-in-n-function-should-not-be-called-directly

Comment: Giovana: I added: dplyr::summarize and no error occours. But the result is not correct. Please compare with my result in my question-post.

Comment: Giovana; your query just count the number of each pagename-element. 4xA, 2xB, 1xC, 1xD