# group_by dplyr within a function NSE

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I am having problems using `dplyr` and `group_by` within a piped function call.

**Reproducible Example:**

Using the following data:

```
ex_data<- structure(list(word1 = c("no", "not", "not", "no", "not", "not", 
"not", "not", "no", "not", "no", "not", "not", "not", "no", "not", 
"no", "no", "not", "not", "not", "no", "not", "without", "never", 
"no", "not", "no", "no", "not", "not", "not", "no", "no", "no", 
"not", "not", "without", "never", "no", "not", "not", "not", 
"not", "not", "never", "no", "no", "not", "not"), word2 = c("doubt", 
"like", "help", "no", "want", "wish", "allow", "care", "harm", 
"sorry", "great", "leave", "pretend", "worth", "pleasure", "love", 
"danger", "want", "afraid", "doubt", "fail", "good", "forget", 
"feeling", "forget", "matter", "avoid", "chance", "hope", "forgotten", 
"miss", "perfectly", "bad", "better", "opportunity", "admit", 
"fair", "delay", "failed", "wish", "dislike", "distress", "refuse", 
"regret", "trust", "want", "evil", "greater", "better", "blame"
), score = c(-1L, 2L, 2L, -1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, -2L, -1L, 3L, 
-1L, -1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, -2L, 1L, -2L, -1L, -2L, 3L, -1L, 1L, -1L, 
1L, -1L, 2L, 2L, -1L, -2L, 3L, -3L, 2L, 2L, -1L, 2L, -1L, -2L, 
1L, -2L, -2L, -2L, -2L, 1L, 1L, -3L, 3L, 2L, -2L), n = c(102L, 
99L, 82L, 60L, 45L, 39L, 36L, 23L, 22L, 21L, 19L, 18L, 18L, 17L, 
16L, 16L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 14L, 14L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
11L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), contribution = c(-102L, 
198L, 164L, -60L, 45L, 39L, 36L, 46L, -44L, -21L, 57L, -18L, 
-18L, 34L, 48L, 48L, -30L, 15L, -30L, -14L, -28L, 39L, -13L, 
13L, -12L, 12L, -12L, 22L, 22L, -10L, -20L, 30L, -27L, 18L, 18L, 
-9L, 18L, -9L, -16L, 8L, -16L, -16L, -16L, -16L, 8L, 7L, -21L, 
21L, 14L, -14L)), .Names = c("word1", "word2", "score", "n", 
"contribution"), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**The regular typical piping operation works as expected:**

```
outside_result<- ex_data %>% 
  mutate(word2=reorder(word2,contribution)) %>% 
  group_by(word1) %>% 
  top_n(10,abs(contribution)) %>% 
  group_by(word1,word2) %>% 
  arrange(desc(contribution)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(word2 = factor(paste(word2,word1, sep = "__"),
                              levels=rev(paste(word2,word1,sep="__"))))
```

**I have implemented the above into a function as given below:**

```
order_bars <- function(df,facetPanel,barCategory,value){
        df %>% mutate(barCategory=reorder(barCategory,value)) %>% 
          group_by(facetPanel) %>% 
          top_n(10,abs(value)) %>% 
          group_by(facetPanel,barCategory) %>% 
          arrange(desc(value)) %>% 
          ungroup() %>% 
          mutate(barCategory = factor(paste(barCategory,facetPanel, sep = "__"),
                                     levels=rev(paste(barCategory,facetPanel,sep="__"))))
      }
```

And taking the advice from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24606282/passing-data-frame-to-mutate-within-function), used `$` notation when referencing variables of a data.frame during mutate operations within a function.

```
inside_result<-order_bars(ex_data,ex_data$word1,ex_data$word2,ex_data$contribution)
```

R throws the following error:

```
Error: unknown variable to group by : facetPanel
Called from: resolve_vars(new_groups, tbl_vars(.data))
```

I suspect `group_by` needs to be tweaked to take either named variables, or I have to use `.dot` notation to reference columns, although I'm just throwing this out into the wind...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to learn how to use 1) the SE versions of `dplyr` verbs such as `group_by_` and `mutate_` and 2) the enigmatic `lazyeval::interp`. Please read `vignette("nse")` carefully.

Then we can come to:

```
order_bars <- function(df, facetPanel, barCategory, value){
  require(lazyeval)
  df %>% 
    mutate_(barCategory = interp(~reorder(x, y), x = as.name(barCategory), 
                                 y = as.name(value))) %>% 
    group_by_(facetPanel) %>% 
    filter_(interp(~min_rank(desc(abs(x))) <= 10, x = as.name(value))) %>% 
    group_by_(facetPanel, barCategory) %>% 
    arrange_(interp(~desc(x), x = as.name(value))) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    mutate_(barCategory = interp(
      ~factor(paste(x, y, sep = "__"), levels = rev(paste(x, y, sep = "__"))),
      x = as.name(barCategory), y = as.name(facetPanel)))
}

order_bars(ex_data, 'word1', 'word2', 'contribution')
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 25 × 6
>    word1    word2 score     n contribution  barCategory
>    <chr>    <chr> <int> <int>        <int>       <fctr>
> 1    not     like     2    99          198    like__not
> 2    not     help     2    82          164    help__not
> 3     no    great     3    19           57    great__no
> 4     no pleasure     3    16           48 pleasure__no
> 5    not     love     3    16           48    love__not
> 6    not     care     2    23           46    care__not
> 7    not     want     1    45           45    want__not
> 8    not     wish     1    39           39    wish__not
> 9     no     good     3    13           39     good__no
> 10   not    allow     1    36           36   allow__not
> ```

Note that we need to replace `top_n` with a `filter_` statement, since no `top_n_` exists. Looking at the source of `top_n` makes it obvious how the `filter_` statement should be constructed.

Or if you want to get fancy, you can write a NSE version of `order_bars`:

```
order_bars <- function(df,facetPanel,barCategory,value){
  facetPanel <- substitute(facetPanel)
  barCategory <- substitute(barCategory)
  value <- substitute(value)

  require(lazyeval)
  df %>% 
    mutate_(barCategory = interp(~reorder(x, y), x = barCategory, y = value)) %>% 
    group_by_(facetPanel) %>% 
    filter_(interp(~min_rank(desc(abs(x))) <= 10, x = value)) %>% 
    group_by_(facetPanel, barCategory) %>% 
    arrange_(interp(~desc(x), x = value)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    mutate_(barCategory = interp(
      ~factor(paste(x, y, sep = "__"), levels = rev(paste(x, y, sep = "__"))),
      x = barCategory, y = facetPanel))
}

order_bars(ex_data, word1, word2, contribution)
```

Ideally, you would write only the SE version fully, and link the NSE version to the SE version with `lazyeval`. I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: this is the first time I've run up against SE and it's a good learning opportunity... thanks for the direction!

Comment: awwww nice answer axeman but man, that SE evaluation stuff is horrible

Comment: @Noobie, Yeah, one pays for the prettiness (in my opinion) of NSE with the ugliness (in my opinion) of SE when using the tidyverse.

Comment: This behaviour has been changed. "dplyr now uses tidy evaluation semantics. NSE verbs still capture their arguments, but you can now unquote parts of these arguments. This offers full programmability with NSE verbs. Thus, the underscored versions are now superfluous." See [programming with dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html)

Answer (score 1):

With `rlang_0.4.0` and `dplyr_0.8.2`, we can use the tidy-evaluation operator ({{...}}) or curly-curly which abstracts quote-and-unquote into a single interpolation step.

```
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)
order_barsN <- function(df, facetPanel, barCategory, value) {
    df %>% 
        mutate(barCategory = reorder({{barCategory}}, {{value}}))%>%
        group_by({{facetPanel}}) %>%
        filter(min_rank(desc(abs({{value}}))) <= 10) %>%
        group_by({{facetPanel}}, {{barCategory}}) %>%
        arrange(desc({{value}})) %>%
        ungroup %>%
        mutate(barCategory = factor(str_c({{barCategory}}, {{facetPanel}}, sep="__"),
                levels = rev(str_c({{barCategory}}, {{facetPanel}}, sep="__"))))

        }


out2 <- order_barsN(ex_data, word1, word2, contribution)
```

-checking with previous answer

```
out1 <- order_bars(ex_data, word1, word2, contribution)
identical(out1, out2)
#[1] TRUE
```