# Error when combining dplyr inside a function

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Using the following training data I compute some frequencies using dplyr:

```
group.count     <- c(101,99,4) 
data   <- data.frame(
    by = rep(3:1,group.count),
    y = rep(letters[1:3],group.count))

data %>%  
group_by(by) %>%
summarise(non.miss = sum(!is.na(y)))
```

Which gives me the outcome I'm looking for. However, when I try to do it as a function:

```
res0   <- function(x1,x2) {
output = data %>%  
    group_by(x2) %>%
    summarise(non.miss = sum(!is.na(x1)))
}

res0(y,by)
```

I get an error (`index out of bounds`). 
Can anybody tell me what I'm missing?
Thanks on advance.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21817110/2461552) shows how to use dplyr with grouping inside a function.

Comment: Great, that was exactly my question. Need to learn how to phrase it better next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this like that in `dplyr`.

The problem is that you are passing it a `NULL` object at the moment. `by` doesn't exist anywhere.  Your first thought might be to pass `"by"` but this won't work with `dplyr` either.  What `dplyr` is doing here is trying to `group_by` the variable `x2` which is not a part of your data.frame.  To show this, make your `data.frame` as such:

```
data   <- data.frame(
  x2 = rep(3:1,group.count),
  x1 = rep(letters[1:3],group.count)
)
```

Then call your function again and it will return the expected output.

Comment: Note that there is a solution: change it to `%>% regroup(list(x2))`, along with changing the function call to `res0(y, "by")`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing the name of your dataframe to df.

This is basically what you have done:

```
df %>%  
  group_by(by) %>%
  summarise(non.miss = sum(!is.na(y)))
```

which produces this:

```
#  by non.miss
#1  1        4
#2  2       99
#3  3      101
```

but to count the number of observations per group, you could use `length`, which gives the same answer:

```
df %>%  
  group_by(by) %>%
  summarise(non.miss = length(y))


#  by non.miss
#1  1        4
#2  2       99
#3  3      101
```

or, use `tally`, which gives this:

```
df %>%  
  group_by(by) %>%
  tally

#  by   n
#1  1   4
#2  2  99
#3  3 101
```

Now, you could put that if you really wanted into a function.  The input would be the dataframe.  Like this:

```
res0   <- function(df) {
df %>%  
    group_by(by) %>%
    tally 
}

res0(df)

#       by   n
#1       1   4
#2       2  99
#3       3 101
```

This of course assumes that your dataframe will always have the grouping column named 'by'.  I realize that these data are just fictional, but avoiding naming columns 'by' might be a good idea because that is its own function in R - it may get a bit confusing reading the code with it in.