# Error All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions. The following do not:

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use dplyr computation as below and then call this in a function where I can change the column name and dataset name. The code is as below:

```
sample_table <- function(byvar = TRUE, dataset = TRUE) {
  tcount <-
    df2 %>% group_by(.dots = byvar) %>% tally() %>% arrange(byvar) %>% rename(tcount = n) %>%
    left_join(
      select(
        dataset %>% group_by(.dots = byvar) %>% tally() %>% arrange(byvar) %>% rename(scount = n), byvar, scount
      ), by = c("byvar")
    ) %>%
    mutate_each(funs(replace(., is.na(.), 0)),-byvar %>% mutate(
      tperc = round(tcount / rcount, digits = 2), sperc = round(scount / samplesize, digits = 2),
      absdiff = abs(sperc - tperc)
    ) %>%
    select(byvar, tcount, tperc, scount, sperc, absdiff)
  return(tcount)
}

category_Sample1 <- sample_table(byvar = "category", dataset = Sample1)
```

My function name is sample_table.
The Error message is as below:-

```
 Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
The following do not:
*  byvar
```

I know this is a repeat question and I have gone through the below links:

- [Function writing passing column reference to group_by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615655/function-writing-passing-column-reference-to-group-by)
- [Error when combining dplyr inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880016/error-when-combining-dplyr-inside-a-function)

I am not sure where I am going wrong. rcount is the number of rows in df2 and samplesize is the number of rows in "dataset" dataframe. I have to compute the same thing for another variable with three different "dataset" names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use column references as strings (`byvar`) (Standard Evaluation) and normal reference (`tcount`, `tperc` etc.) (Non Standard Evaluation) together.
Make sure you use one of both and the appropriate function: `select()` or `select_()`. You can fix your issue by using

```
select(one_of(c(byvar,'tcount')))
```

Comment: I'm having this same issue and cannot figure out how to fix it. It was working a few weeks ago with ```mutate_each(funs(as.numeric), matches("name"))``` but now it's throwing an error. Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried `mutate_at` ? Otherwise I suggest make a new question.