# compare_means(): "must resolve to integer column positions, not a symbol" when using string/symbol in formula

Tags: r

I'm trying to do ANOVA with `compare_means()`. Using the sample dataset `ToothGrowth` as an example, I want to achieve something like this:

```
#directly calling column name
compare_means(len~supp, data=ToothGrowth, group.by = "dose", method = "anova")
```

except that my `supp` in the formula is a string.

Directly passing the string as an argument results in an error in the model formula. So I tried converting the string to name or symbol:

```
#convert string column name to name/symbol
x <- as.name("supp") #as.symbol("supp")
compare_means(len~x, data=ToothGrowth, group.by = "dose", method = "anova")
```

But both returned the same error:

> Error: `x` must resolve to integer column positions, not a symbol

I have checked similar error messages like [Error All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions. The following do not:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41587473/error-all-select-inputs-must-resolve-to-integer-column-positions-the-followin), but none of them seem to address my issue.

Please instruct what I should do. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

So I saw [How to use reference variables by character string in a formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024685/how-to-use-reference-variables-by-character-string-in-a-formula) and solved the problem using

```
f <- "len~supp"
do.call("compare_means", list(as.formula(f), data=as.name("ToothGrowth"),
    group.by = "dose", method = "anova"))
```