# Error : Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : Column `col1` is unknown

Tags: r, function, group-by, dplyr, tidyverse

Error :  Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) :    Column `col1` is unknown

```
pivot <- function(df, col1, col2){
  df %>%
    group_by(col1, col2) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    spread(col2, n, fill = 0)
}
```

Running the command `pivot (iris, Species, Petal.Width)`

Can anyone tell why this error message ? and how to solve it

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `group_by_` for programming.

```
library(tidyverse)
pivot <- function(df, col1, col2){
  df %>%
    group_by_(col1, col2) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    spread(col2, n, fill = 0)
}

pivot (iris, "Species", "Petal.Width")
```

This should work too. Don't need to quote the columns here.

```
pivot <- function(df, col1, col2) {
  group_var1 <- enquo(col1)
  group_var2 <- enquo(col2)
  df %>% 
    group_by(!!group_var1, !!group_var2) %>% 
    summarise(n = n())
}

pivot (iris, Species, Petal.Width)
```

The output on the second is easier to read, I think.

For more information, see [dplyr: How to use group_by inside a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815060/dplyr-how-to-use-group-by-inside-a-function) and https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer is:

```
pivot <- function(df, col1, col2){
  col1<-deparse(substitute(col1))
  col2<-deparse(substitute(col2))
  df %>%
    group_by_(col1, col2) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    spread(col2, n, fill = 0)
}

pivot (iris, Species, Petal.Width)
```