# How can I use dplyr to apply a function to all non-group_by columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use the dplyr package to apply a function to all columns in a data.frame that are not being grouped, which I would do with `aggregate()`:

```
aggregate(. ~ Species, data = iris, mean)
```

where `mean` is applied to all columns not used for grouping. (Yes, I know I can use aggregate, but I'm trying to understand dplyr.)

I can use `summarize` like this:

```
species <- group_by(iris, Species)
summarize(species,
          Sepal.Length = mean(Sepal.Length),
          Sepal.Width = mean(Sepal.Width))
```

But is there a way to have `mean()` applied to *all* columns that are not grouped, similar to the `. ~` notation of `aggregate()`? I have a data.frame with 30 columns that I want to aggregate, so writing out the individual statements is not ideal.

Comment: See this previous **[SO Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295936/can-dplyr-summarise-over-several-variables-without-listing-each-one)**.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you're willing to try out an experimental dplyr, you can try out the
new (and still experimental) `summarise_each()`:

```
devtools::install_github("hadley/dplyr", ref = "colwise")

library(dplyr)
iris %.%
  group_by(Species) %.%
  summarise_each(funs(mean))
## Source: local data frame [3 x 5]
## 
##      Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
## 1     setosa        5.006       3.428        1.462       0.246
## 2 versicolor        5.936       2.770        4.260       1.326
## 3  virginica        6.588       2.974        5.552       2.026

iris %.%
  group_by(Species) %.%
  summarise_each(funs(min, max))
## Source: local data frame [3 x 9]
## 
##      Species Sepal.Length_min Sepal.Width_min Petal.Length_min
## 1     setosa              4.3             2.3              1.0
## 2 versicolor              4.9             2.0              3.0
## 3  virginica              4.9             2.2              4.5
## Variables not shown: Petal.Width_min (dbl), Sepal.Length_max (dbl),
##   Sepal.Width_max (dbl), Petal.Length_max (dbl), Petal.Width_max (dbl)
```

Feedback much appreciated!

This will appear in dplyr 0.2.

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Even returns NaN for groups that are all missing data.

Comment: I can't replicate the error on the iris data sets. But i have data that that gives true when I do all(a$date == a$CALENDAR_YEAR_MONTH). But doing group_by(a, date) %.% summarise_each(funs(median = median(.,na.rm=T), mean)) gives Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , list(median = median(CALENDAR_YEAR_MONTH,  : 
  Column 1 of result for group 4 is type 'integer' but expecting type 'double'. Column types must be consistent for each group.

Comment: fyi, `summarize_each()` has been deprecated in favor of `summarize_all()`

Answer (score 4):

This will get you almost all the way in `dplyr`.

```
h = iris %.%
  group_by(Species) %.%
  do(function(d){
    sapply(Filter(is.numeric, d), mean)  
  })

as.data.frame(h)
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `do()` in that way, as it's likely to change in 0.2

Comment: Is there an idiomatic way to do it in `dplyr`? In `data.table` I can do `data.table(iris)[,lapply(.SD, mean),Species]`.