# dplyr: How to use select and filter inside functions; (...) not working for arguments

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to build some functions for creating standard tables from a questionnaire, using dplyr for the data manipulation. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815060/dplyr-how-to-use-group-by-inside-a-function) was very helpful for the group_by function, passing arguments (in this case, the name of the variable I want to use to make the table) to `(...)`, but that seems to break down when trying to pass the same arguments to other dplyr commands, specifically 'select' and 'filter'. The error message I get is `'...' used in an incorrect context'`.

Does anyone have any ideas on this? Thank you

For the sake of completeness (and any other hints - I'm very new to writing functions), here is the code I would like to use:

```
myTable <- function(x, ...) {
df <-  
    x %>%
    group_by(Var1, ...) %>%
    filter(!is.na(...) & ... != '') %>% # To remove missing values: Not working!
    summarise(value = n()) %>%
    group_by(Var1) %>%
    mutate(Tot = sum(value)) %>%
    group_by(Var1, ...) %>%
    summarise(num = sum(value), total = sum(Tot), proportion = num/total*100) %>%
    select(Var1, ..., proportion) # To select desired columns: Not working!

tab <- dcast(df, Var1 ~ ..., value.var = 'proportion')
tab[is.na(tab)] <- 0
print(tab)
}
```

Comment: It is tricky, because when you use `...` it is hard to guess what exactly you intend to pass in. Though I don't think this is the right approach -- if you pass in names of variables, that won't work because group_by doesn't take quoted arguments.

Comment: check out this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21296364/1727133 and also the functions `mutate_each` and `summarise_each`

Comment: @AndrewMacDonald you should make a new answer for that question you linked using `summarise_each`

Comment: Thanks @AndrewMacDonald, I had seen that question while searching for an answer yesterday. It's a great addition to dplyr, but I had a lot of problems getting it to work with the 'proportion' calculation. In any case, I'd still like to figure out how to pass arguments to the ... part. Maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree and there's a much simpler way to do this. For today, my work-around has been to rewrite the function using melt and dcast instead... I'll post that up if anyone cares to see it

Comment: I think this doesn't work basically because of a bug in dplyr that I plan to work on for the next release.

Comment: I'm still having this issue, passing vars into a function, is this fixed?